# Como fazer uma range com letras do alfabeto em python?

Tags: python, lista

No PHP, quando queremos fazer um `array` de letras do alfabeto, podemos usar a função `range`.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
$letras = range('a', 'z');
```

Resultado:

```
Array (
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
    [7] => h
    [8] => i
    [9] => j
    [10] => k
    [11] => l
    [12] => m
    [13] => n
    [14] => o
    [15] => p
    [16] => q
    [17] => r
    [18] => s
    [19] => t
    [20] => u
    [21] => v
    [22] => w
    [23] => x
    [24] => y
    [25] => z )
```

E também é possível fazer isso através do `for`

```
for ($a = 'a'; $a != 'aa'; $a++) echo $a;
```

Resultado:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Mas no Python, quando tento fazer isso através da função `range`, um erro é retornado.

Exemplo Python:

```
 range('a', 'z');
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.

Então a pergunta é: De maneira mais simples possível, como poderia gerar uma lista de letras do alfabeto em `python`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import string
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

print a
```

Resultado:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

Fonte: [StackOverflow - Alphabet range python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16060899/1964435)

Caso não queira o alfabeto inteiro pode fazer assim:

```
import string
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:14])

print a
```

Ou ainda usando `range()` e `ord()`:

```
a =[]

# list de a-n
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('n')+1):
    a.append(chr(i))

print a
```

Resultado para ambos os casos:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

Fonte: [StackOverflow - Python: how to print range a-z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190122/python-how-to-print-range-a-z)

Comment: Para com isso! Poxa, essa me surpreendeu! Vou migrar de vez pro `python`

Comment: Hahaha.. Essa também me surpreendeu :D

Comment: Você precisa conhecer os frameworks web, sugiro começar pelo Flask. PHP nunca mais :P

Comment: Note que em geral, você sequer precisa criar essa lista- pode usar o string.ascii_lowercase direto - já que strings funcionam como sequências.

Comment: Hahaha também me surpreendeu :D

Answer (score 1):

Gosto de usar o `range` com o `ord`, como já citado

```
#python3.*
abc=[]
for k in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
  abc.append(chr(k))
print(abc)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cria lista de 'A' até 'ZZ' (702 elementos)

Crie uma lista vazia para usar a função append e insert, crie também uma variável contadora para marcar a posição dos primeiros caracteres.

```
alfabeto = []
c = 0
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    alfabeto.insert(c, chr(i))
    c += 1
    for j in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
        alfabeto.append(chr(i)+chr(j))
```

O laço consiste em inserir os caracteres de A até Z nas primeiras posições da lista e acrescentar os demais caracteres no fim seguindo a ordem natural.

## Cria lista de 'A' até 'ZZZ' (18278 elementos)

Exemplo recíproco da função acima, necessário mais uma variável contadora para inserir os elementos na posição correta de AA até ZZ.

```
alfabeto = []
c = 0
d = 0
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    alfabeto.insert(c, chr(i))
    for j in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
        d += 1
        alfabeto.insert(c+d, chr(i)+chr(j))
        for k in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
            alfabeto.append(chr(i)+chr(j)+chr(k))
    c += 1
```

Neste caso podemos observar a necessidade do contador A~Z estar posicionado ao fim dos laços 'j e k'.

Obviamente, ideia utilizada da solução de Math♦, quem respondeu acima. :)

Comment: Essa resposta está correta  mas é importante um pouco de texto descrevendo o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Explique o que está acontecendo.